# Access Secured Web service in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, security

I have to consume a secured (https) web service, which requires a domain user credentials. I have following code to access the service.

```
    public string GetResponse()
    {
        var web = new ProxyStatisticsWebServiceSoapClient();
        web.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
        web.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("username",
            "password", "domail");
        var result  = web.QueryProxyStatistics();

        return result;
    }
```

Whenever I call `web.QueryProxyStatistics();` method, I get `MessageSecurityException` exceptions. (The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.) is there anything wrong with code?

Comment: Can you post your client service configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
web.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =  System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

Comment: please post your configuration settings: server and client.